# Stop fb.me as contentTitle while sharing Link on Facebook using FBSDKShareLink?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdksharekit

I am trying to share link on FB via `FBSDKShareLink` and I am providing a dynamic url to `content.contentURL` for callback to open my app. Now when I share on FB, the link always shows `fb.me` as content title and content discription. Can anyone guide me how to stop this?

```
let content: FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
let userInfo : AnyObject =  LocalStore.userDetails()!
let iosLink = responseDictionary?["fb_link"] as? String
let name = userInfo["name"] as? String
content.contentURL = NSURL(string: iosLink!)!
content.contentTitle = "click it"
content.contentDescription = "My Custom Description"
content.imageURL = NSURL(string: "http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/dog/dog-07.jpg")!
FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to post the unique ***App-Linking url*** that opens my app to a specific page for that i was publishing the url generated from app's server end.

If i am sharing the above url by ***FBSDKShareLinkContent*** , then the url reads fb.me and there were no parameter to change this

***Since fb reads the meta data to provide content title and content description, which the url was not having [ also fb do not allow to give meta data to the dynamic app linking urls]*** . I presented one fb sharing dialog box and and displayed the content which user wanted to share and then ***posted by graph api*** not from ***"fbsdkshare"***